# Xamarin Forms app hangs and exits when debugging on iOS Device

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, mono

I have an app which runs just fine whenever I'm not debugging it on an iOS device. I can debug it in the simulator. I can run it on the device. I just can't debug it on the device.

When I set a breakpoint at the start of FinishedLaunching the debugger hits the breakpoint. However, if I step through to the following line which is a Caliburn Micro IoC call to get the app, it hangs on this line for a few seconds then crashes:

```
_theApp = IoC.Get<App>();
```

This all began to happen after I did a few upgrades to Visual Studio for Mac, Xamarin.iOS and Xamarin.Forms, although I don't know which one because I was behind on updates.

Here's what I found in my VS .log file. So there is an exception associated with the issue but I don't know what it means:

Can someone help? Thanks!

```sh
INFO [2020-02-07 16:35:53Z]: [iOS Debugger] Connected to "iPhone" over USB on port 47593.
ERROR [2020-02-07 16:36:11Z]: The connection with the debugger has been lost. The target application may have exited.
Mono.Debugging.Soft.DisconnectedException: The connection with the debugger has been lost. The target application may have exited. ---> Mono.Debugger.Soft.VMDisconnectedException: Exception of type 'Mono.Debugger.Soft.VMDisconnectedException' was thrown.
  at Mono.Debugger.Soft.Connection.disconnected_check () [0x00018] in /Users/runner/runners/2.164.6/work/1/s/monodevelop/main/external/debugger-libs/Mono.Debugger.Soft/Mono.Debugger.Soft/Connection.cs:1344 
  at Mono.Debugger.Soft.Connection.SendReceive (Mono.Debugger.Soft.Connection+CommandSet command_set, System.Int32 command, Mono.Debugger.Soft.Connection+PacketWriter packet) [0x000d9] in /Users/runner/runners/2.164.6/work/1/s/monodevelop/main/external/debugger-libs/Mono.Debugger.Soft/Mono.Debugger.Soft/Connection.cs:1657 
  at Mono.Debugger.Soft.Connection.EnableEvent (Mono.Debugger.Soft.EventType etype, Mono.Debugger.Soft.SuspendPolicy suspend_policy, System.Collections.Generic.List`1[T] mods) [0x00371] in /Users/runner/runners/2.164.6/work/1/s/monodevelop/main/external/debugger-libs/Mono.Debugger.Soft/Mono.Debugger.Soft/Connection.cs:2528 
  at Mono.Debugger.Soft.EventRequest.SendReq (System.Collections.Generic.List`1[T] mods) [0x00097] in /Users/runner/runners/2.164.6/work/1/s/monodevelop/main/external/debugger-libs/Mono.Debugger.Soft/Mono.Debugger.Soft/EventRequest.cs:106 
  at Mono.Debugger.Soft.BreakpointEventRequest.Enable () [0x0002e] in /Users/runner/runners/2.164.6/work/1/s/monodevelop/main/external/debugger-libs/Mono.Debugger.Soft/Mono.Debugger.Soft/BreakpointEventRequest.cs:25 
  at Mono.Debugger.Soft.VirtualMachine.SetBreakpoint (Mono.Debugger.Soft.MethodMirror method, System.Int64 il_offset) [0x00009] in /Users/runner/runners/2.164.6/work/1/s/monodevelop/main/external/debugger-libs/Mono.Debugger.Soft/Mono.Debugger.Soft/VirtualMachine.cs:295 
  at Mono.Debugging.Soft.SoftDebuggerSession.InsertBreakpoint (Mono.Debugging.Client.Breakpoint bp, Mono.Debugging.Soft.BreakInfo bi, Mono.Debugger.Soft.MethodMirror method, System.Int32 ilOffset) [0x00000] in /Users/runner/runners/2.164.6/work/1/s/monodevelop/main/external/debugger-libs/Mono.Debugging.Soft/SoftDebuggerSession.cs:1203 
  at Mono.Debugging.Soft.SoftDebuggerSession.InsertBreakpoint (Mono.Debugging.Client.Breakpoint bp, Mono.Debugging.Soft.BreakInfo bi) [0x00000] in /Users/runner/runners/2.164.6/work/1/s/monodevelop/main/external/debugger-libs/Mono.Debugging.Soft/SoftDebuggerSession.cs:1196 
  at Mono.Debugging.Soft.SoftDebuggerSession.ResolvePendingBreakpoint (Mono.Debugging.Soft.BreakInfo bi, Mono.Debugger.Soft.Location l) [0x00007] in /Users/runner/runners/2.164.6/work/1/s/monodevelop/main/external/debugger-libs/Mono.Debugging.Soft/SoftDebuggerSession.cs:3136 
  at Mono.Debugging.Soft.SoftDebuggerSession.ResolveBreakpoints (Mono.Debugger.Soft.TypeMirror type) [0x0022d] in /Users/runner/runners/2.164.6/work/1/s/monodevelop/main/external/debugger-libs/Mono.Debugging.Soft/SoftDebuggerSession.cs:2645 
  at Mono.Debugging.Soft.SoftDebuggerSession.HandleTypeLoadEvents (Mono.Debugger.Soft.TypeLoadEvent[] events) [0x00061] in /Users/runner/runners/2.164.6/work/1/s/monodevelop/main/external/debugger-libs/Mono.Debugging.Soft/SoftDebuggerSession.cs:2164 
  at Mono.Debugging.Soft.SoftDebuggerSession.HandleEventSet (Mono.Debugger.Soft.EventSet es) [0x00147] in /Users/runner/runners/2.164.6/work/1/s/monodevelop/main/external/debugger-libs/Mono.Debugging.Soft/SoftDebuggerSession.cs:1703 
  at Mono.Debugging.Soft.SoftDebuggerSession.EventHandler () [0x0005d] in /Users/runner/runners/2.164.6/work/1/s/monodevelop/main/external/debugger-libs/Mono.Debugging.Soft/SoftDebuggerSession.cs:1625
```

Comment: It's hard to know why form the logs. I would suggest you to fire an issue at [Mono Github](https://github.com/mono/mono/issues).

Comment: Ok, I will do this ASAP. Thanks

Comment: I think this may have been a simple matter of my Xamarin.Forms package versions being out of sync between the Forms/iOS projects. It is debugging on the device fine now. What threw me is the Release version was working. My Release/Debug build settings have different linker settings. That is probably why.

Comment: OK, you should use  Xamarin.Forms package with same version in the Forms/iOS project.